# jQuery conflicting with mobile menu

Tags: jquery, mobile, menu

I am noticing that the mobile menu is not working on certain pages when using this jQuery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.js"></script>
```

If I remove this jQuery everything works fine. The only issue is I need to use the jQuery for a 3D brochure I use on the site. It seems it cant work with out it.

[image: console screenshot]

Comment: To be able to help you you should provide the code of the mobile menu.

Comment: Magnific popup requires a jQuery version of 1.9.1 and above. Update the jQuery version you are using and try again. This is the latest version in the CDN: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`